# Rotate two canvas simultaneously in a single page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two canvas.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1338 px" height="550px" ></canvas>
<canvas id="annCanvas" width="1338 px" height="550px"></canvas>
```

In ist canvas(id='canvas') i am loadig an image.

In 2nd canvas(id='annCanvas') i am drawing shapes (e.g. Rectangle,Line etc).

I want to rotate both canvas simultaneouly.(with four rotation value 0,90,180,270).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You want to rotate `canvas` objects or content of `canvas` objects (i.e. images, rectangles, lines)?

Comment: Actually i am new in html5. I want to know that-- is there difference between rotating canvas and rotating canvas element--? Because if we rotate canvas then its content will also rotate automatically ... am i correct or not sir..

Answer (score 0):

You can use css animation , and apply that animation to those canvass..

```
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1338 px" height="550px" class="rotate_anim"></canvas>
<canvas id="annCanvas" width="1338 px" height="550px" class="rotate_anim"></canvas>
```

and your css should be like this

```
    .rotate_anim{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: animation1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite ;
    }

@-webkit-keyframes animation1
{
0%{ -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg);
}
25%{ -webkit-transform:  rotate(90deg);
}
50%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    75%{ -webkit-transform:  rotate(270deg);
    }
    100%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for Answer dear..I wish that this will work for me.. But i am getting confuse that how would i implement this css for me. i have to rotate canvas from buttons.. Will you please tell me the way to implement it.

Comment: On your mouse event generate the css and insert it dynamically ,using insertRule api

Comment: Here is the Way to Implement it,
 

First take your css as a string,
    var rule=" your css";
    var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];      
    var ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;
    mySheet.insertRule(rule,ruleIndex );

NB. I have used "-webkit" keyword for "webkit" based browser,  you can use "-moz" for Mozilla, "-o" for opera "-ms" for Internet Explorer